# How do I write test for error throwing in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, lambda, jasmine

I would like to test if error has been thrown.

Here is my example code:

```
export const lambdaHandler = async (event: any, context: any, callback: any) => {

switch(param) {
   case 1: /.../
   case 2: /.../
   default: throw new Error('error')
   }
}
```

Tests which I've tried

```
await lambdaHandler(event, {}, i.callback);

expect(lambdaHandler).toThrow();
```

and also

```
const res = await lambdaHandler(event, {}, i.callback);

expect(res).toThrow();
```

```
const res = await lambdaHandler(event, {}, i.callback);

expect(res).toEqual('error');
```

and

```
await lambdaHandler(event, {}, i.callback);

expect(async ()=> {
   await lambdaHandler(event, {}, i.callback);
}).toEqual('error');
```

```
await lambdaHandler(event, {}, i.callback);

expect(async ()=> {
   await lambdaHandler(event, {}, i.callback);
}).toThrow();
```

method

```
.toThrowError()
```

doesn't work for me too.

The result which I generally get is

```
 Message:
    Error: error
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `async matchers` instead because you are trying to test a Promise. Something like this should work for you

```
await expectAsync(async ()=> {
  await lambdaHandler(event, {}, i.callback);
}).toBeRejectedWithError('error');
```

You can read more [in the docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/async-matchers.html)

Hope it helps